mapping over the array object is not rendering the array values in component

i have set an array to localstorage first and then get it  by json.parse correctly and map through it it's rendering the component as i want for each array object but when i'm trying to get the data into every element it's not showing the data in li element but showing the li what is the issue
> 

`type here
>>store.jsx
const handleUserList = () =>{
   const newUserList  =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userList'))
    if(newUserList){
         setUserList (newUserList);
         
    }
    else{
        return <h1>user not found</h1>
    }}
>>userList.jsx
const UserList = () =>{
  const {userList} = useContext(UserListOperations)
  console.log(userList);
        return(
            
            <ul >
        {userList.map((user)=>{
            console.log(user.id);
            return (
             
               
                   <User key ={user.id} user={user}/>
             
            )
         }
        )}
         
         
         </ul>
           
        )
  }
>>user.jsx
const User = ({user}) =>{
    return (
        <li>
            {user.userName}
        </li>
    )
}``

i have tried to access the array data into my component but it's not happening
